# GitVersion VSTS Custom Config

Tags: azure-devops, gitversion

I am using GitVersion with my VSTS build definition and I need to configure it to ignore commit messages `commit-message-incrementing: Disabled` because I have an old commit message with a totally wrong version number.

I've added a `gitversion.yml` file with the above line to the root of my project but its being ignored.

How do I configure this setting for my VSTS build definition?

Comment: How did you config the GitVersion.yml, did you add the content `no-bump-message: 'commit-message-incrementing: Disabled'` in the file?

Comment: Which version of GitVersion are you using?  Is this on hosted build agent, or are you running your own build agent?  If the latter, are you doing a fresh clone of the repository each time?

Comment: @Marina - MSFT: As per https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/ I just used the line `commit-message-incrementing: Disabled` That link doesn't imply I should combine it with the `no-bump-message` config option?
@Gary Ewan Park - as per https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/1317 - thanks :)

Comment: @DaleBurrell You can find the no-bump-message (Used to tell GitVersion not to increment when in Mainline development mode) in global configuration part. And there has another solution for the question: use custom condition to skip GitVersion task when the commit message is `commit-message-incrementing: Disabled`.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT using `no-bump-message: 'commit-message-incrementing: Disabled'` caused GitVersion to throw an error. Your second comment suggests to disable the GitVersion task. But I do want the GitVersion task to run, I just want GitVersion to *only* use tags when calculating the version, and ignore commit messages.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark trying locally with 3.6.5 after having removed the cache - but I can see from the output that GitVersion is using the commit messages in its algorithm. Whereas when I use the `ignore` setting and exclude specific commits I can see that it is indeed ignoring them.

Comment: Actually its probably down to my misunderstanding `commit-message-incrementing: Disabled` probably doesn't affect the base version calculation (which is what I need to control) - would that be correct?

Comment: In all honesty, I am not sure. I would suggest using the ignore configuration, if that is working out for you, and perhaps raise a bug/feature request around the other.